# Prove |E| = |V| - 1 by induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, trees

Any idea how to do this? I need to prove that let T = (V, E) be a tree, and then prove by induction that |E| = |V| - 1. Thankyou!

Comment: Are you being required to prove it by induction?  Forward or reverse induction?  (I.e., growing the tree from a single node, or reducing it to a single node?)  Either way, you have to justify that you can "get there from here", but otherwise, at each step, you note that both $|E|$ and $|V|$ increase (or decrease, respectively) by one, and hence the equality still holds.

Comment: @BrianTung, nice question, but the question just says to prove it by induction. I don't even know what is forward or reverse induction. What is easy for you may prove it that way. :)

Comment: Well, suppose you start from a single vertex.  We then have $|E| = 0, |V| = 1$ and the base case is established.  Now, add single edges until you produce the desired tree $T$.  At each step, you add an edge, so $|E|$ goes up by $1$, but you also add a vertex (otherwise, the graph would no longer be a tree, if you used two existing vertices), so $|V|$ also goes up by $1$, and the induction step is also established.  The tricky part is to show that any given $T$ can always be produced in this manner.

Comment: That's great @BrianTung. Thanks. Just one question is this the explanation and I need to do something else or I can submit this explanation as an answer proof?

Comment: @BrianTung, I have a doubt. Does it prove that |E| = |V| - 1 ? I don't think so. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is this a binary tree?

Comment: @Bram28, not quite sure, but we have studied binary tree. If you know how to prove, please share your knowledge with us. :)

Comment: @Carlos: It does prove it, as long as you provide justification for the basic structure I provided.  You need to establish that any tree $T$ can be produced by starting from a single vertex, and adding edges one at a time.  That's the induction.  It shouldn't matter whether it's a binary tree or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so base case: just a single vertex, no edges. So: $|E| = |V|-1$ since 0 =1-1

Inductive step: Suppose we have a tree with a top vertex, and two subtrees $T_1$ and $T_2$ below this top vertex. By inductive hypothesis, we can assume that for the two trees it holds that $|E_1| = |V_1| -1$ and $|E_2|=|V_2|-1$. Now, we have a total of $|V|=|V_1|+|V_2|+1$ vertices in the tree as a whole, and $|E|=|E_1|+|E_2| + 2$ edges. So: $|E|=|E_1|+|E_2|+2 = |V_1| -1+|V_2|-1+2= |V_1|+|V_2|+1-1=|V|-1$ as desired.

So, by structural induction, we have our desired result.

Ok so that is for binary trees. If nodes can have any number of children, you can generalize the proof to that as well, using the inductive hypothesis that $|E_i|=|V_i|-1$ for every subtree.